how to make a video play 2x faster in jsx react landing page
I have already tried using playbackRate (debugging with Claude and GPT—no luck). I want the video to run at twice the playback speed when the user scrolls to it on the landing page. I am aware that I could do a simple workaround of saving the video in 2x and then just removing the syntax causing the error, but I want to learn the more robust way.
    <div className="relative inline-flex flex-col">
      <video
        className="md:max-w-none mx-auto rounded"
        width={500}
        height={462}
        autoPlay={true}
        playbackRate={2}
        muted
        loop
      >
        <source src="/videos/DatasetDealFacilitation.mov" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <video
        className="md:max-w-none absolute w-full left-0 transform animate-float"
        width={500}
        height={44}
        autoPlay={true}
        playbackRate={2}
        muted
        loop
        style={{ top: '30%' }}
      />
    </div>

Type '{ children: Element; className: string; width: number; height: number; autoPlay: true; playbackRate: number; muted: true; loop: true; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement>'.
  Property 'playbackRate' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement>'.ts(2322)


The playbackRate attribute is not a valid HTML attribute for the <video> element. You can only change the playbackRate attribute through JavaScript like this:
// play video 2x faster
document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 2.0;


Amazing thanks! Works like a charm.

@AnshTandon glad it helped!
